# Using Angular1 services with Ionic2/Angular2 app: No provider for service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ionic2, bootstrapping

I'm trying to create new Ionic2 app that uses some of my Ionic1 Angular services. I've read https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html and know i should use UpgradeAdapter but for some reason it doesn't work.

Here is my `app.ts` file that bootstraps Ionic2 app:

```
// This is to tell TS that `require` method is in fact available
declare function require(name:string);

import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ionicBootstrap } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

let angular = require('angular');

import { UpgradeAdapter } from '@angular/upgrade';
let adapter = new UpgradeAdapter();

angular.module('myAngular1App', [])
     .service('MyAngular1Service', function() {
        return {
            hello: function() {
                console.log('Hello!')
            }
        }
    });

adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['myAngular1App']);

adapter.upgradeNg1Provider('testService');

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/app.html'
})
class MyAngular2App {
    constructor(@Inject('testService') testService) {
        console.log('construct');
        testService.hello();
    }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyAngular2App, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Without the Angular1 `testService` injecting it works fine, but with it i see DI exception **`No provider for testService!`**:

[image]

What am i missing here?